# Azure pipeline. not releasing new objects into on-prem database

Tags: sql-server, azure-pipelines, azure-releases

So my issue is that my new SQL objects are not being released into my on-prem database. Now if I alter existing objects it works fine. I see the update passed through the release and on the on-prem SQL database. When i create a new table or procedure. it doesn't release. It builds, it links the build to release just fine. When I run the manual release I get no errors but in the logs, I do not see the new proc or table in the "deploy using: dacpac" log.
I do see my commits in the build and in the master branch.

- Is there a setting that I'm missing?
- For new objects to be released
  to the on-prem database?

The account that I'm using has full admin right to this database.
please let me know if you need any screenshots or samples.

Comment: i read this article and no help. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70095101/stored-procedure-is-not-deployed-to-azure-sql-server-after-running-the-pipeline

Comment: So far i found out that my builds are not writing to my dacpac file. Model.xml. Can anyone help? I do find the new objects in my agent folder though.